# Вычисление по формуле, с указ. точностью

Tags: c, математика, ряды

Помогите пожалуйста, решить задачку
Необходимо  рассчитать сумму ряда Тейлора  с указ. точностью  и с максимальной точностью (n - максимальное значение, при которых расчет формулы корректен).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(int n, int x)
{
    double res;
    res = pow(x, 2*n + 1);
    res *= pow(-1,n);
    res *= (double)powf(-0.5, n);
    return res;
}

factorial(n)
{
    int r, s;
    s = 2 * n + 1;
    for (r = 1; s > 1; r *= (s--))
        ;
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    float e;
    double sum = 0;
    int n = 0, x=0;
    double previous, current, S;

    scanf("%d\n", &x);
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    scanf_s("%f", &e);  
    current = f(n,x)/factorial(n);
    sum += current;
    n++;
    do
    {
        previous = current;
        current = f(n,x);
        sum += current;
        n++;
    } while (abs(current - previous) > e);

    printf("sum = %f\n", sum);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: и в чём проблема?

Comment: А, ну вообще у вас N вводится пользователем, а оно должно быть 0 изначально.

Comment: у меня результат, получается какое-то левое число

Comment: А что это за мешанина из scanf и scanf_s? В чем идея?

Comment: Язык С уже давно не разрешает опускать тип `int`. `int factorial(int n)`, а не `factorial(n)`. И вообще-то задачи на нахождение суммы ряда Тейлора - это в первую очередь задачи на правильные приемы суммирования плавающих чисел: либо от меньших к большим, либо Кэхэн, либо еще что-то. Почему-то об этом забыли...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уж или `n` задавайте, или точность, но не одновременно :)

Ряд знакопеременный, так что точность достигается, как только отброшенный член по абсолютному значению меньше этой самой точности.

```
double sum(double x, double eps)
{
    double s = x, t = x;
    x *= x;
    for(int n = 1; fabs(t) > eps; ++n)
    {
        s += t *= -x/(2.*n*(2.*n+1));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Вот так это посчитать проще всего. Используем отношение двух соседних членов ряда для вычисления очередного члена на основе предыдущего.

Я использую именно **точность**. Думаю, переписать для числа членов ряда - труда не составит?

[Тут](https://ideone.com/tUborj) можно посмотреть сравнение с реальным синусом...

Comment: Harry, можете мне вставить то что вы написали в мой код и показать? А то я боюсь что опять какую-то фигню сделаю и ничего не будет работать, пожалуйста

Comment: Нет. Уж такие мелочи за вас я делать не буду. Здесь помогают, а не делают готовые работы. Я сознательно немного изменил ответ - не 100% под ваше условие - чтобы это была именно помощь, и вы приложили свою часть труда, чтобы понять, как это работает. Вы новичок на сайте, так что маленькое пояснение - напиши вы просто условие задачи - вопрос был бы очень быстро закрыт (с формулировкой *Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно*). Но вы что-то писали - поэтому я постарался подтолкнуть вас к правильному решению. Но не писать за вас..